# ORA-12008 - ошибка на стороне сервера, к которому обращяюсь по запросу

Tags: sql, oracle

```
"ORA-12008: ошибка в пути обновления материализованного представления
ORA-12801: ошибка в сервере P013 параллельного запроса
ORA-00600: код внутренней ошибки, аргументы: [kcblsltio_1], [1761608064], [353411335], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-02063: предшествующий 2 lines из B2BGW
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2821
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3058
ORA-06512: на  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3017
ORA-06512: на  line 6
```

"

Comment: Укажите версию Oracle DB

Comment: При возникновении `ORA-00600` - лучше обратиться в Oracle Support